# Can't run minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft

I have Oracle Java, I am opening it as an executable.

Minecraft runs perfectly on my Windows computer, but I want it on my Ubuntu laptop.

When I open Minecraft I get as far as the launcher, but when I press play it halts with the following exception:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/thomas/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-13673203295934/liblwjgl64.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/thomas/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-13673203295934/liblwjgl.so: /home/thomas/.minecraft/versions/1.8.1/1.8.1-natives-13673203295934/liblwjgl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at bss.I(SourceFile:2488)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
```

Comment: This comment:  "So I have oracle".  Are you running Oracle Linux?  If so you are in the wrong place, this is Ubuntu forums.

Comment: @JohnKirchner I would assume he means Oracle **Java**.

Comment: I see, the comments from OP are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using an ARM cpu, which minecraft does not support.

Comment: So I won't be able to run minecraft because of my processor?

Comment: @ThomasBrogan, yes.  Minecraft downloads and uses several native libraries that are only supported on i386 and amd64.